# laravel event listener for session expire, as no logout event listener called on session expiry

Tags: php, laravel, session, events, laravel-5

the scenario is simple: i want a single user to be logged in from only one device at a given time. using laravel framework version 5.2

---

here is my work so far to achieve this, using event listeners:

i set a is_logged_in flag in users table which is ON when user logs in. and based it its ON status it will reject all the subsequent request of log in from same user.

i used login attempt, login and logout events to achieve this:

1. on login attempt listener the following code is executed. it will check if the user is already logged in then a flag logged is set in session.

```
       $user = User::select('is_logged_in')->where('email', $event->credentials['email'])->first();
        if($user->is_logged_in == 1){
            Session::put('logged', 'Yes');
        }else{
            Session::put('logged', 'No');
        }
```

2. now at login event, the session flag logged is checked, if its set then user is forcefully logout, maintaining the remember_token (which is changed on logout)

```
    if(session('logged') == "Yes"){
        $previous_remember_token  = $event->user->remember_token;
        $previous_usesr_id = $event->user->id; 
        Auth::logout();
        $user = User::find($previous_usesr_id);
        $user->remember_token = $previous_remember_token;
        $user->save();
    }else{
        $event->user->is_logged_in = 1;
        $event->user->save();
    }
```

3. and in logout even i used following code to reset user database flag of is_logged_in:

```
    if(session('logged') != "Yes"){ 
        $event->user->is_logged_in = 0;
        $event->user->save();
    }
```

now here are the issues im facing:

1. When session expires, logout even is not executed, how can i execute my logout event code on session expire? is there any session:expire event listener present in laravel? 
   1.1 This also leads to another question what how laravel monitor session time, and where it saves it? how and when laravel framework make the session as expired?
2. i also want to execute the logout code when the user close the tab or browser, which is really hard but i think may be some ajax function updating the users table column after a certain interval and write a cron job to check the interval and switch OFF the flag in DB, is there any better way to do this, please guide?

Comment: The whole point of a session is to connect web server to the current user, so once its expired, you basically "loose" connection between the two parties. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to notify the user on the browser that the session has expired, you could potentially send ajax request every x amount of time to a certain route which checks if user is authenticated and if not handle it on the front end.

Comment: @Vilius lets say i want to execute some code on logout event, but when session expires, the user is logged out, but the logout event is not fired by laravel, thats the question. how can i catch logout event caused by session expire?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own session driver handler in laravel and execute the code you want in "destroy" and "gc" events of your handler.

You can simple copy the default DatabaseSessionHandler code from
Illuminate/Session/DatabaseSessionHandler.php
and name it lets say CustomeSessionHandler.php.

make sure to register the new handler in AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
  Session::extend('custom', function ($app) {

      $connection = $app['config']['session.connection'];
      $table = $app['config']['session.table'];
      $lifetime = $app['config']['session.lifetime'];
      $connection = $app['db']->connection($connection);
      return new CustomSessionHandler($connection, $table, $lifetime, $app);
  });
}
```

and in your .env or your config/session.php
use the new driver

SESSION_DRIVER=custom